# Why does this python script run normally when started manually but give an error when run on boot as a service on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, python, services, threads

I made a bot for cryptocurrency trading which works normally when I start it manually, but when you automate the operation of the Ubuntu service it starts with the following error:

```
end at Sun 2022-04-24 14:02:48 UTC. --
:     self.run()
:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
:     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
:   File "/home/ubuntu/ea_cripto/orion_cript.py", line 120, in analiseAN
:     analisador= analiseEstrategica(cliente, 'BRL')
:   File "/home/ubuntu/ea_cripto/analiseAtivos.py", line 21, in __init__
:     self.Storage= storage(r)
:   File "/home/ubuntu/ea_cripto/dbinstancia.py", line 26, in __init__
:     self.db= sqlite3.connect('./database.db')
: sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
: Exception in thread Thread-2:
: Traceback (most recent call last):
:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
:     self.run()
:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
:     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
:   File "/home/ubuntu/ea_cripto/orion_cript.py", line 148, in streamTickers
:     dadosStorage= storage(x)
:   File "/home/ubuntu/ea_cripto/dbinstancia.py", line 26, in __init__
:     self.db= sqlite3.connect('./database.db')
: sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
: Importações efetuadas com sucesso
: algoritimo entrando na parte de execução de funções.
: Exception in thread Thread-3:
: Traceback (most recent call last):
:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
```

The service that runs the script is:

```
[Unit]
Description=RoboOrion - Script que inicializa  robo Orion cript
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=ubuntu
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 30
ExecStart= /usr/bin/python3  /home/ubuntu/ea_cripto/orion_cript.py
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The code works from three threads, I've already done the following alternatives:

I put a sleep interval of 10 minutes for code initialization.
assign chmod 777 permission to the service
I changed the way to pass the arguments to the classes inside the thread's functions.
I'm just afraid to mess more with the bot code because it works well starting manually so I don't know what else to do. if anyone can help thank you.

Comment: I don't work in your environment, but it's possible that this is a permissions problem, where you're not executing in both cases under the same user account.

Comment: When I run manually I run on the same user is that what you mean?

Comment: When you run manually you use your login, but your script seems to run with `User=ubuntu`. It would surprise me if your user-name was `ubuntu`.

Comment: since you are executing as a user other than root, perhaps waiting until after multi-user.target is reached would help. right now, you are just waiting on the network to be up before launching. its probably best if you wait until the system is fully booted before launching your service.